# context.getSharedPreferences crashes app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use SharedPreferences in my app, but it crashes my app.

What I'm trying to do is getting SharedPreferences to work in multiple activities.

Here is the codes:

```
public class Question{
    boolean answered;
    int id;
    String userAnswer;
    String QuestionP = LogoQuiz.QuestionP;

    public Question(int i, Context context){
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(QuestionP, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = i;
        answered = false;
    }


}
```

A class for saving status of the question

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public static ArrayList<Question> ques;
    public static final String QuestionP = "QuestionSettings";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(QuestionP, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = pref.edit();

        -------- activity ----------
        -------- activity ----------

        ques = new ArrayList<Question>();
            ques.add(new Question(i, null));
    }
}
```

The activity of my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ques.add(new Question(i, null));
```

to

```
ques.add(new Question(i, Main.this));
```

You are passing `null` in the `Question` constructor and then try to call `getSharedPreferences` on it so you get a `NullPointerException`

Or since you are not using `pref` anywhere in the constructor change your constructor to

```
public Question(int i)
{
    id = i;
    answered = false;
}
```

and in your `Main` activity change

```
ques.add(new Question(i, null));
```

to

```
ques.add(new Question(i));
```

Comment: Or, since `Question` is not actually using the `SharedPreferences`, get rid of the second `Question` constructor parameter and get rid of the first line of the `Question` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

pass context to your question class object while adding the object to arraylist

```
ques.add(new Question(i, null));
```

you are using context in your question's constructor but not providing any context here,change it to:

```
ques.add(new Question(i, Main.this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getSharedPreferences on a Context that is null. Therefore you get a **NullPointerException** because you can't call getSharedPreference on null. You have to use

`ques.add(new Question(i, this));`

You should declare the variable "i" too.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot pass context as null to you question java class. We can get the shared pref value using the Application/Activity context. Here you have passed context as null in ques.add(new Question(i, null)); that means you are trying to het the shared pref from null context that is the reason you are getting the null pointer exception and your app crashes.

Please change your methods call to

```
ques.add(new Question(i, Main.this));
```

Here Main.this refers to your activity context. You can also pass getapplicationContext() here as sharedPref are local to application.